# Issues using which in R for loop

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have two dataframes. The first dataframe is a list of genetic variants, their identifiers, and their position on a chromosome. The second is a list of genes where columns in each row specify the start and stop position of a gene on a chromosome.

I want to see which genetic variants fall within a gene's 'range' denoted by the start_20 and stop_20 cols. A genetic variant may fall into the range of more than 1 gene. For example, here snp "rs1" will map to gene A and gene B.

This is what I have tried so far:

df of genes ranges

```
chromosome<-c("1", "1", "2")
start_20<-c("1", "1", "5")  
stop_20<-c("4", "4", "6")  
gene<-c("A", "B", "C") 

genelist=data.frame(chromosome, start_20,  stop_20, gene,stringsAsFactors=F  )
```

df of snps and their positions

```
chromosome<-c("1", "2")
snp<-c("rs1", "rs2")
position<-c("3", "5") 

snplist=data.frame(chromosome,snp,position,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Aim is to match snps to genes via base pair positions (i.e snp 1 has a    position of '3' meaning it maps to gene A and gene B).

```
genelist.bychrome <- vector("list", 2)
```

List of genes by chromosome.

```
for(i in 1:2) genelist.bychrome[[i]] <- genelist[genelist[,"chromosome"]==i,]
```

Empty container of length nrow(snplist)
 Put matched genes in here if you find one

```
gene.matched <- rep("",nrow(snplist))

gene.matched<-as.list(gene.matched)

#looping across each observation in snplist

    for(i in 1:nrow(snplist)){

# snplist[i,"chromosome"] is the chromosome of interest
# Because of consecutive ordering genelist.bychrome[[3]] gives the genelist       for chromosome 3

 Therefore, genelist.bychrome[[ snplist[i,"chromosome"] ]] gives the genelist for the chromosome of interest

 VERY IMPORTANT: get.gene gives the index in genelist.bychrome[[     snplist[i,"chromosome"] ]], NOT genelist

        if(snplist[i,"chromosome"] <= 1){ 

                get.gene<- which((genelist.bychrome[[ snplist[i,"chromosome"] ]][,"stop_20"] >= snplist[i,"position"])  &    

            # get matching list element of genelist.bychrome 
            # in this element collect indices for rows where stop position is greater than the postion of the snp and
            # start position is less than the position of the snp
            # this should collect multiple rows for some snps   
            # dump the gene for this index in the matching element of gene.matched 
            # i.e get.gene<- which(genelist.bychrome[[1]]  [,"stop_20"] >= snplist[1,3])  & (genelist.bychrome[[1]]  [,"start_20"] <= snplist[1,3])
            # gene.matched <- genelist.bychrome[[1]][get.gene,"gene"]


                    ( genelist.bychrome[[ snplist[i,"chromosome"] ]][,"start_20"] <= snplist[i,"position"])) # correct                  
                        if(length(get.gene)!=0) gene.matched[i]<- genelist.bychrome[[ snplist[i,"chromosome"] ]][get.gene,"gene"]
                             } 

                                    } # end for()

#bind the matched genes to the snplist
    snplist.new <- cbind(snplist,gene.matched)
```

Any tips would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You say, "snp 1 has a position of '3' meaning it maps to gene 7 and 8". How do you know position 3 maps to 7 & 8?

Comment: Hello, sorry I just realized that was a mistake in my question (I wrote a new version to make it more intuitive). Gene 7 and 8 should now read gene A and gene B.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is in the which statement inside the For loop. As it is this line would work as intended if you add as.numeric(). Try this,  `genelist.bychrome[[as.numeric(snplist[i,"chromosome"]) ]]`

But in general, I'd suggest defining numeric vectors as numeric data types unless you have a reason to do otherwise, such as your chromosome vector can be defined as c(1,1,2) instead of c("1","1","2"). And also use `as.numeric()` whenever you're working with numeric data defined as strings, such as when referring to list index, comparison operations, etc.

let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks that indeed helped! I will make sure I remember to do that in the future. However now the vectors in the loop don't match up as I get the 'number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length' message. Given that a snp may match to more than one gene I want gene.matched to be list of character vectors of length 'snplist' like so: gene.matched <- list(c("geneA", "geneB"), c("geneC")) which I can append to the snplist. Having some trouble trying to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

Update: issue resolved by removing the first if statement, casting the vectors 'as.numeric' as suggested, and making a empty list of no predetermined length at the start (which may be not always be a good idea I would guess).

Thanks!

```
#make data frames

     genelist = data.frame(chromosome=c(1,1,2),start_20=c(1, 1, 5), stop_20=c(4, 4, 6), gene=c("A", "B", "C"), stringsAsFactors=F)

     snplist=data.frame(chromosome=c(1,2),snp=c("rs1", "rs2"),position=c(3,5),stringsAsFactors=F)

 #objective is to get genes per snp

    genelist.bychrome <- vector("list", 2)
    for(i in 1:2) genelist.bychrome[[i]] <-   genelist[genelist[,"chromosome"]==i,]  

    gene.matched <- list()

 #looping across each observation in snplist

    for(i in 1:nrow(snplist)){

                get.gene<-  which((genelist.bychrome[[as.numeric(snplist[i,"chromosome"]) ]] [,"stop_20"] >=  snplist[i,"position"])  &                         
                    (genelist.bychrome[[as.numeric(snplist[i,"chromosome"]) ]] [,"start_20"] <= snplist[i,"position"]))

                        if(length(get.gene)!=0) gene.matched[[i]]<- genelist.bychrome[[ snplist[i,"chromosome"] ]][get.gene,"gene"]

                            }                   

    names(gene.matched)=snplist$snp
```